# How to check if purchase status is complete

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I need to check into a arquivo.phtml if the purchase is complete. If it's with status complete, it will be displayed, if not with full status, displays a message "You do not have complete purchase"

To call all purchases this code is used

`<php $ _orders = $ this-> GetOrders ();`

And to call only those with full status, how do?

Comment: What does complete mean?  When the order's been taken?  When it's been authorized? When it's been captured?  When it's been fully shipped?

Comment: Complete applications, and when the client makes the request, the payment is confirmed, the product is shipped and is shipped to Customer Tracking, Order Tracking. Thanks

Comment: How are you handling customer tracking?  How are you handling order tracking?  Are these third party plugins that alter order status?  Is it a completely offline process?  Do people manually change the order status, properties or comments to update it with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got personal, I had to change the core for this.

With the help of a friend (http://www.icefusion.com.br) ..

in app / code / core / Mage / Sales / Block / Order / history.php
placed this construct he sent me instead of what's there!

```
    public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->setTemplate('sales/order/history.phtml');
//TODO: add full name logic
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'complete'))
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
$this->setOrders($orders);
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setHeaderTitle(Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Orders'));
}
```

Done, done that, on page seudominio.com.br / history.phtml Shopping with displays only the status of Complete.

Thanks to everyone who helped or tried.

Answer (score 1):

This will check the orders to see if they are complete, adjust to fit your needs:

```
$_orders = $this->getOrders();

foreach($_orders as $_order){
  if($_order->getStatusLabel()=='Complete'){
    echo 'You have a complete purchase';
  }
  else {
    echo 'You do not have a complete purchase';
  }
}
```

Comment: This code checks for purchase with complete status, but to check for and purchase with complete status and if you only buy with this status (complete) is displayed. If not nothing is displayed?
Anyone help?